# Running tornado & hosting app on different port

Tags: python, hosting, tornado

I have a Tornado web chat that must absolutely run on the default port 80 for various reasons such as authentication etc. However the Tornado web server is running on port 8800 for obvious reasons (if it is possible to host Tornado on the same port as my website, I'd be willing to try), so what I'm trying to accomplish is to run Tornado web server through my console while hosting the Tornado web chat on my website's default port.

I moved the web chat's index.html to my website default folders so it is like ***www.example.com/webchat.html*** rather than ***www.example.com:8800/webchat***. I then run tornado with the command

```
python webchat.py
```

But when I visit webchat.html the chat isn't running as it would if it were on port 8800 because 
the page is not rendering the python.

**Webchat HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="width: auto; height: 100%;">

         <span>{% raw content %}</span> <!-- The span is not rendered on page -->



</div><!-- /.container -->

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

{% if 'chat' in globals() and chat %}
    <!-- Application script -->
    <script src="{{ static_url('stuff.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        {% end %}
```

Comment: "However the Tornado web server is running on port 8800 for obvious reasons" - what are these reasons? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: The reasons are that Tornado is a web server and you can not run two web servers (other being apache) on the same port address......

Comment: That makes sense. Not everyone is running a server on port 80, so sometimes it is useful to explicitly mention it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what authentication issues force you to run webchat on port 80?

Comment: Tornado has a premade login for my webchat which is written in python, I prefer to use PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two options:

1. If your website is static, you can ditch the apache server, move your website to tornado, and get tornado to serve your website on the `/` path. Then run tornado on port 80. This is probably the easiest. Add the following as your last tornado handler:

   `(r'/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': static_path}),`

   `static_path` should be the path to your apache-served website root directory.
2. If you need the apache server, then you can configure apache as a reverse proxy for your tornado server. From [Need help setting up: Apache Reverse Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282587/need-help-setting-up-apache-reverse-proxy), it looks like you need to add this to your `apache.conf`:

   `ProxyPass /webchat http://localhost:8800/webchat
   ProxyPassReverse /webchat http://localhost:8800/webchat`

   You will need to load the specified Apache modules as well.

You could also try using Tornado's WSGI functionality and then configure Apache with `mod_wsgi`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'd be more keen to try option 2 because tornado doesn't function with php unless you load the php with javascript. I'll update you and accept answer if it works