# ActionScript FTP socket Security Sandbox Violation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ftp

I'm attempting to write a file to an `ftp` server with ActionScript. I've put a `crossdomain.xml` in the root directory, and my application accepts it: `OK: Policy file accepted: ftp://ftp.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml`. However I still get a security sandbox violation:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to ftp://ftp.mydomain.com:21 halted - not permitted from https://www.mydomain.com.localhost/path/App.swf'
```

Does this have something to do with the `.localhost` loopback, or is there something off with my policy file? Something else? Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S.: I've also tried `Security.allowDomain` and `Security.allowInsecureDomain`, but to no avail.

Comment: For me the trick would be to create a vhost on your server and to use proxypass and proxyreverse. I'm not expert in that domain but I think you should look in that direction. I should help your two url to communicate together. Have a look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282587/need-help-setting-up-apache-reverse-proxy)

Comment: If you connect over socket you should give crossdomain.xml over socket not just put it in the root. Read more about it http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000471.html