# Apache with PHP and .NET Core at the same time

Tags: php, apache, .net-core

Lets imagine we have two different apache virtual hosts and we want one host to be php web-site and the other one - .net core. The simple question - how to configure apache (httpd.conf/php.conf) to make this happen?
For php we already have directives:
`AddHandler php5-script .php` and `AddType text/html .php`, for the php virtual host we have settings:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.20.22:80>
 ServerName phpsite.ru
 ServerAlias www.phpsite.ru
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpsite.ru/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/phpsite.ru/public >
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/phpsite.ru/public/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/html/phpsite.ru/public/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

What should we do to make a second virtual host handle through .net core?

Comment: Let's save imagination for Christmas and search [how to setup reverse proxy apache virtual host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282587/need-help-setting-up-apache-reverse-proxy). Assuming you can setup php only vhost and .net core only vhost, what problem you are facing combining both together?

Comment: Thx, and somehow i missed this article: http://tattoocoder.com/using-apache-web-server-as-reverse-proxy-for-aspnetcore/